# List of OMAPI supported devices

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, open-mobile-api, secure-element

I'm developing with the Open Mobile API but so far haven't found a list of devices that support the API by default (by default being using the OEM ROM).

I realise that since API level 21, Android telephony supports sending APDUs via basic and logical channels dirctly through the TelephonyManager. But I'd like to know about devices running pre-API level 21 too.

So, has a list already been compiled of devices with built-in support or is there a way to find out for myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of any complete list. However, there is a not so comprehensive one in our report [Open Mobile API: Accessing the UICC on Android Devices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03027) and there is another one (though now unmaintained) in the [SEEK-for-Android Wiki](https://github.com/seek-for-android/pool/wiki/%5BUNMAINTAINED%5D-Devices#commercial-devices).

If you have access to each of the devices you are interested in, you could, of cource, check if the smartcard system service is available on them:

```
final String SMARTCARD_SERVICE_PACKAGE = "org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service";
try {
    PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(SMARTCARD_SERVICE_PACKAGE, 0);
    // smartcard service present
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex) {
    // smartcard service NOT present
}
```

Or you could simply create an app that declares to require the Open Mobile API library by adding the following uses-library entry to its AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi" android:required="true" />
```

If that app can be installed on a device, this indicates that the device contains the Open Mobile API library.

This may also be a way to obtain a more comprehensive list of supported devices: You could create such an app and publish it on Google Play. Google Play will filter based on `<uses-library />` entries that have the required attribute set to `true` (`android:required="true"`); see also [`<uses-library>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html) and [Filters on Google Play](https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#manifest-filters). This means, that once you uploaded such an app to Google Play, you should be able to get a list of suuported devices that essentially matches all devices that have the Open Mobile API library available on them.

Comment: Thanks very much, your report was one of the first sources I came across and has been a great help. I decided to create a Google Play Developer Console account (one-time $25 fee) and currently looks like building for API level 16 ~1/4 of devices are supported (3099/13128).

Comment: @AReubens Note that I'm not sure how reliable the detection mechanism through Google Play is...

Answer (score 4):

While @Michael Roland response still stands, it's also worth noting that since [Android 9 Pie, Open Mobile API is part of the Android](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/08/introducing-android-9-pie.html).

So for API level 28 and higher, every phone has OMAPI by default and there is no need for explicit check.

Comment: Mind that, even if the OMAPI is present, a device can choose to not expose it's readers. Pixel 1 & 2 behave this way. Pixel 3 exposes its reader.

Comment: And consequently there is no longer any `<uses-library>` or `<uses-permission>` required. (Please confirm.)