# How to exchange APDUs without rooting the device?

Tags: apdu

I have written an applet on a sim card and successfully installed it on my sim. Now I want to send/receive APDUs to my sim card applet using an android application.

Some libraries (e.g. Seek) need rooted devices and do the task but I don't want to root devices.
Is there any android libraries to interface my applet? All I have found is applications to use NFC or Bluetooth to send or receive APDUs to contactless cards, but I need to interface contact sims inserted to mobile sim card slot.

### Appendix 1:

These are all applets existing on my USIM (output of GPShell list function):

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect -readerNumber 1
select -AID A000000151000000
Command --> 00A4040008A000000151000000
Wrapped command --> 00A4040008A000000151000000
Response <-- 6F108408A000000151000000A5049F6501FF9000
open_sc -scp 2 -scpimpl 0x55 -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
Command --> 805000000853160BA36116264B00
Wrapped command --> 805000000853160BA36116264B00
Response <-- 000081210103B99E856DFF020032D2AE118D648EC6F57DFA6581CCC39000
Command --> 8482010010395D6343C2D216F30460633603DD27A2
Wrapped command --> 8482010010395D6343C2D216F30460633603DD27A2
Response <-- 9000
get_status -element 20
Command --> 80F22000024F0000
Wrapped command --> 84F220000A4F0075545E9C0668BCDA00
Response <-- 07A0000001515350010005A000000087010006A00000025108010010A0000000090005FFFFFFFF8915000000010008A000000151100303010010A0000000185000000000000052418050010007E0E1E2E3E4E501010008A00000015141434C01009000

List of elements (AID state privileges)
a0000001515350  1       0
a000000087      1       0
a00000025108    1       0
a0000000090005ffffffff8915000000        1       0
a000000151100303        1       0
a0000000185000000000000052418050        1       0
e0e1e2e3e4e501  1       0
a00000015141434c        1       0
get_status -element 40
Command --> 80F24000024F0000
Wrapped command --> 84F240000A4F0023B1458CFDA5C36100
Response <-- 10A0000000871002FF82FF3089010000FF070410A0000000871004FF47F00189000001FF070010A000000087ABCDFF47F00189000001FF070007A0000002510801070009A00000015110030301870010A0000000185000000000000052418041070009A0000000035350410107C009A0000000035350410207C009A0000000035350410307C009A0000000035350410407C009A0000000035350410507C009A00000000353504106078008E0E1E2E3E4E50102070209A00000015141434C0007029000

List of elements (AID state privileges)
a0000000871002ff82ff3089010000ff        7       4
a0000000871004ff47f00189000001ff        7       0
a000000087abcdff47f00189000001ff        7       0
a0000002510801  7       0
a00000015110030301      87      0
a0000000185000000000000052418041        7       0
a00000000353504101      7       c0
a00000000353504102      7       c0
a00000000353504103      7       c0
a00000000353504104      7       c0
a00000000353504105      7       c0
a00000000353504106      7       80
e0e1e2e3e4e50102        7       2
a00000015141434c00      7       2
card_disconnect
release_context
```

`e0e1e2e3e4e50102` is my applet and `a00000015141434c00` is allow all ARA applet.

Comment: I don;t think that Android SDK has such functionality, therefore - only rooted device (or installing your app as system app, which requires root acces)

Comment: Does `iccExchangeSimIO` do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Android 9 there is [android.se.omapi](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/se/omapi/package-summary) package providing such access (implementing [SIMalliance Open Mobile API](https://simalliance.org/se/se-technical-releases/)). For older devices supporting OMAPI, see e.g. [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290527350_Open_Mobile_API_Accessing_the_UICC_on_Android_Devices), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42037149/5128464), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657627/list-of-omapi-supported-devices).

To get access to your applet there has to be an ARA-M applet on SIM configured to allow your application to connect to your applet (there is a MIT licensed implementation available [here](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/aram-applet) and a special all-allowed implementation [here](https://github.com/seek-for-android/allow-all-ara)).

Access configuration can be performed with [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/wiki/Secure-Element-Access-Control).

Disclaimer: A lot has changed since I was dealing with this so please do validate my thoughts.

Good luck!

Comment: Do you know any guide or sample scripts to configure ARA-M applet? It always returns me `Failed to communicate with card in JnaCardTerminal{scardHandle=SCardContext{cd00000100000001}, name=ACS ACR83U 0}: SCardTransmit got response 0x57 (null: null)` when trying to run gp commands

Comment: Is that just manually install ARA-M alongside my sim applets and do the configurations?

Comment: @MJay When do you get this error? When installing ARA-M applet or when configuring it? SEEK for Android contains a simple ARA-M implementation which always allows all access -- maybe try [this one](https://github.com/seek-for-android/allow-all-ara) first.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it right now. I get this error while configuring ARA-M.

Comment: I tested allow-all-ara-master. I installed it on my sim card along with my applet by which I want to communicate. But again, I cannot connect to sim card, android application says `No Sim card inserted` and `sim card is locked` and OS says `sim card is locked`. Is there anything I have forgotten to do? Thanks for your help vlp.

Comment: Did your SIM work in the phone before (e.g. was it able to register to the network)? There needs to be a working (U)SIM application present on the card.

Comment: I own have a Java usim (smart card), which is programmed with a customized applet by an ACR reader connected to PC. So, my usim is not a general sim card.

Comment: My phone is single slot sim. I insert my usim into sim slot. When I turn on the phone, os displays `SIM is blocked`.

Comment: @Mjay I understand you have a Java Card, but does it have a (U)SIM applet loaded and personalized? Phone expects SIM card to support e.g. [TS 51.011](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=2793), [TS 31.10](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=1803) which must be implemented somehow...

Comment: can you please see 'Appendix 1' I just inserted (editted) in my main question post. I added list of applications on my USIM. If there is something missing, where can I get SIM applet to load on my sim?

Comment: @Mjay USIM AID should start with `A00000000900001` (as per [ETSI TS 101 220](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101200_101299/101220/12.00.00_60/ts_101220v120000p.pdf)) and there is no such application. You might try sending e.g. `A0A40000027F10` to verify `DF TELECOM` presence (as per TS 51.011). If you have an off-the-shelf Java Card then there almost certainly won't be any U(SIM) application loaded and personalized...

Comment: ...I don't know where to get a working SIM card with known GP keys (but you might find [Sysmocom SIM/USIM cards for sale](http://shop.sysmocom.de/t/sim-card-related/sim-cards) useful). Please do validate my thoughts as my hobbyist GSM experience ended several years ago (before 2.5G).

Comment: Can I find those applets anywhere to install them manually on my U(SIM)?

Comment: @Mjay I don't know. Probably not.. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks, just I have to mention that my USIM only supports `ETSI TS 102 221 (Class A, B, C)`, `EMV2000` and `ISO7816` standards.