# Understanding how to access the embedded secure element

Tags: android, nfc, secure-element

I have been looking at this blog https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/08/accessing-embedded-secure-element-in.html, this is really good however I am having trouble understanding how to add the com.android.nfc_extras to my project. Also, the way the etc/nfc_access.xml file works. 
If there is anyone that will help me break through this process then it will be nice, since I am new to this.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends. 
The most basic answer is: **disregard the article (it's 6 years old, Android changed a lot!) and try to use [GlobalPlatform Open Mobile API](https://globalplatform.org/)**. It is API for accessing secure elements present on many phones.

Expanded answer: it varies between manufacturers. Some will allow you to access their embedded secure element (eSE) via OMAPI, sometimes you might need to use propietary service as a proxy. One example of vendor-specific service is Samsung KMS Agent (still, eSE is visible in OMAPI).

After that introduction, if you want to access eSE and you are new to this, **you probably want to use OMAPI**. If you are writing app targeting Android P - great news, [OMAPI is now part of Android](https://www.nfcworld.com/2018/03/14/356680/android-p-to-include-support-for-globalplatform-open-mobile-api/).

But in reality you would probably target older Android version, so bad news is - you don't know if OMAPI is present on the phone. See: [List of OMAPI supported devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657627/list-of-omapi-supported-devices)

But assuming you have OMAPI present, then take a look at Android documentation for OMAPI: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/se/omapi/package-summary and [GlobalPlatform.org](https://globalplatform.org/) documentation e.g. [OMAPI docs](https://globalplatform.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/GPD_Open_Mobile_API_Android_Binding_v0.0.0.5_for_OMAPI_v3.3_PublicReview.pdf)